# parsing xml file using ajax in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am getting xmlhttp.status 0 when i work with following code i searched when i will get xmlhttp.status as 0 i found that if i use local files then i will get response as 0 and when i run the code i am getting response null.

```
    <script language="javascript">
    var xmlhttp;
    function init() {
       // put more code here in case you are concerned about browsers that do not provide XMLHttpRequest object directly
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    function getdetails() {
        var txtDate = document.getElementById("txtDate");
        var url = "http://192.168.1.31:8080/CFL/seam/resource/restv1/test?date=" + txtDate.value;
        xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                  if ( xmlhttp.status == 0) {
                        var det = eval( "(" +  xmlhttp.responseXML + ")");
                var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(xmlDoc);
                 }
                 else
                        alert("Error ->" + xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
        };
    }
  </script>

<body  onload="init()">

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="jquery-datepicker-disable-future-dates.aspx" id="form1">
       <center>Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="txtDate" type="text" id="txtDate"  /><br /><input type="button" value="Get Details" onclick="getdetails()"/></center>
       <div id="div1"></div>
   </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This security restriction prevents the XMLHttpRequest object from
requesting resources outside the domain from which the script was originally served.

So you have to host the above code in a file within the domain 192.168.1.31:8080 to get it working,